# Python Beautiful Soup not looping results

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

Im using BS4 for the first time and need to scrape the items from an online catalogue to csv.
I have setup my code however when i run the code the results are only repeating the first item in the catalogue n times (where n is the number of items).
Can someone review my code and let me know where i am going wrong.

Thanks

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer


#response = requests.get('https://my.supplychain.nhs.uk/Catalogue/browse/27/anaesthetic-oxygen-and-resuscitation?CoreListRequest=BrowseCoreList')
response = requests.get('https://my.supplychain.nhs.uk/Catalogue/browse/32/nhs-cat?LastCartId=&LastFavouriteId=&CoreListRequest=BrowseAll')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text , 'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all(class_='productPrevDetails')
#print(items)
for item in items:
    ItemCode = soup.find(class_='product_npc ').get_text().replace('\n','')
    ItemNameS = soup.select('p')[58].get_text()    
    ProductInfo = soup.find(class_='product_key_info').get_text()

    print(ItemCode,ItemNameS,ProductInfo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always see the first result because you are searching `soup`, not the `item`. Try

```
for item in items:
    ItemCode = item.find(class_='product_npc ').get_text().replace('\n','')
    ItemNameS = item.select('p')[58].get_text()    
    ProductInfo = item.find(class_='product_key_info').get_text()

    print(ItemCode,ItemNameS,ProductInfo)
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for the help :)